# How can I show my Android App name instead of my package name in the Dev Console as well as show the app icon in the App manager of the phone?

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile

When I uploaded my android app the the console, I checked the details and it showed the Package name in the top right corner. Is their a way for me to change it to show the actual application name instead? When I download it onto my phone and then during the uninstall progress screen it shows the package name, and I would much rather have the actual App Name instead. Also It doesn't show the app icon in my phone's application manager, is shows a default android App.

I have scoured the internet for answers, but it must be something simple because I can find no help anywhere.